# How to replace <link href="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico"> in html with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, favicon

How to replace href attribute in a  tag NOT and  tag.

So replace https://www.google.com/favicon.ico with https://www.bing.com/favicon.ico by search for the string in the href.

```
<link href="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico"> in html with jquery or javascript?
```

This should work with an  tag but does NOT seem to work with the  tag.

```
$("link[href='https://www.google.com/favicon.ico']").attr('href', 'https://www.bing.com/favicon.ico')
```

I'm trying to replace the favicon source in the header with the js-console.

Comment: 1. Look at the `href` you're searching for in the selector, and what the actual value is in the HTML. 2. The `<link>` element is intended for including external content in a page, which makes the URL you're using very questionable. If you're trying to create a clickable link, use `<a>` instead

Comment: `href='https://www.google.com/'` won't match `href="www.google.com"`.

Comment: Added more details, is it still not clear?

Comment: $("#link").attr("href", $("#link").attr("href").replace("google","bing"));

Comment: `document.querySelector("link[href='https://www.google.com/favicon.ico']").href = "https://www.bing.com/favicon.ico";`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#link").attr("href", "https://www.google.com/jquery/");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="https://www.google.com" id="link">Google.com</a></p>

<button>Change href Value</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't work. Just with the console, no click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It should be work.

```
<a id="link" alt="Link" href="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico">Google</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "https://www.bing.com/favicon.ico");
</script>
```

Comment: there is usually no id, how without an id?

Comment: Check this:

`
document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "https://www.bing.com/favicon.ico");
`